# How to determine the outer class of a nested class structure in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, type-deduction

Imagine, you have a nested class structure like the one below:

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        struct C{};
    };
};
```

If you have given an instance of C, called c like

```
A::B::C c;
```

is it possible to deduce

- the most outer class (here A)
- the next class in hierarchy (here B)
- the number of nestings (here 2)

via templates, compile-time recursion and template-specialization techniques? I've tried several templates like the following below:

```
template<typename Outer , typename Inner , typename Outer::Inner>
struct nested
{
    typedef typename Outer::Innter type;
};
```

but as you can see, i am not able to do a recursion for stepwise deduction of B and C. Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: I'd be curious to know what problem you're trying to solve by knowing the nested structure

Comment: Simply spoken, it is for a verbose algorihm.

Comment: Can you explain the downvote, please? I want to understand my mistakes and improve my posts!

Comment: Sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you hoping to achieve through these inner classes?  There may be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Only thing I can think about is to make your classes inherit from a template class that stores the information. A simple solution might be https://godbolt.org/g/jWpa72 - You can of course extend this to e.g. not except primitives as parents

Comment: The code I have to handle is 3rd party originated. Because of the lack of time, I am not able to re-implement this code.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a traits that you manually feed for that:

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        struct C{};
    };
};

template <typename T> struct outter {
    static constexpr const std::size_t count = 0u;
};

template <> struct outter<A::B::C>
{
    using type = A::B;
    static constexpr const std::size_t count = 2u;
};

template <> struct outter<A::B>
{
    using type = A;
    static constexpr const std::size_t count = 1u;
};
```

Comment: For the few cases I have to deal with, this could be a possible solution. Thanks a lot for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

No. As far as the compiler is concerned, `A`, `A::B` and `A::B::C` are independent unrelated classes (except for name lookup / scope).

You might be able to do something at runtime if you know the format of your implementation's `type_info::name()`.